# How to access Huion Tablet driver settings on Xubuntu (XFCE) 22.04.3 LTS?

Tags: drivers, xubuntu, tablet

I followed the official instructions given by Huion for downloading their tablet drivers on Linux (I use a Huion Inspiroy H610X), and the driver seems to work for the most part.

One issue, however, is that I cannot access the settings application for the driver where I can assign shortcuts to the tablet buttons and adjust other settings.

I'm very new to Linux in general; when using the tablet on Windows, I can easily open up the tablet driver settings from the system tray by clicking the HuionTablet icon.

On Xubuntu, however, I see no such system tray, and clicking the HuionTablet icon doesn't work. (In Task Manager, "huionCore -d" is active. If I click on the tablet icon in the panel again, two other Huion processes (*huiontablet.sh* and *huiontablet/huiontablet -d*) are started and immediately afterward are automatically terminated. I'm unsure of whether or not that has anything to do with the issue I face, but will mention it just in case.)

Is there a way that I can access the tablet driver settings?

I would appreciate any help on this matter.
Thank you.